# Paddle Payment - The checkout id must be a valid checkout id

Tags: next.js, payment

I try to integrate Paddle as a payment service in my Next.js App.
I keep getting this error on localhost:

> The checkout id must be a valid checkout id

I tried both overlay and inline checkout following [this](https://developer.paddle.com/getting-started/ZG9jOjI1MzUzOTgx-build-a-paddle-checkout-in-10-minutes) tutorial.
For simplicity I created a minimal html file to test. I get the same error there:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.paddle.com/paddle/paddle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      Paddle.Setup({ vendor: MY_ID)
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#!" class="paddle_button" data-product="MY_PRODUCT">Buy Now!</a>
  </body>
```

I don't have a domain approved but the docs say that localhost should work without. Vendor ID and Product ID are correct of course.
I already contacted the support a few days ago but they barely respond and are not helpful yet. Maybe someone of you know how to fix the problem?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @johnnycardy Yes, the support had to enable the checkout for me manually because I haven't submitted a custom domain.

Comment: thanks. I got a response from support, and in my case, they had to actually enable checkouts on my account even though my domain was approved already.